# How To See If One Date Is Newer Than Another

Tags: android, date, time

Hello I think I have a very simple question but i'm having trouble figuring it out.

I Got the Date and Time In Android using this code

```
String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());
```

It gave me back this value

```
Apr 21, 2016 9:30:16 PM
```

how do I compare using to dates with that value so if I want to see if

```
Apr 21, 2016 9:30:16 PM
```

is newer or older than

```
Apr 21, 2016 9:35:16 PM
```

How would I check that Thanks

**Attempt One**

I Tried This

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
            Date fileDate = format.parse(date1);

DateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
            Date metaDate = format.parse(date2);
```

this the value for date 1 and 2 being

```
Apr 21, 2016 9:35:16 PM
```

But it threw a parse exception. I must use that value above so What do I Need to do so it doesn't break the code when it tries to parse the date

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use Date.before(), rather than comparing the strings.  In fact its easier to convert the string back into a date than use the strings.

Comment: Must have date and time though it needs to be that specific

Comment: You need to change the format string to match the format of your date

Comment: makes sense though

Comment: that first line of code in my question is what formats the month and time that way I didn't make it that way